# CakePHP get associated data inside beforeSave

Tags: cakephp

Does anybody see what I'm doing wrong?

The `$brand['slug']` is empty when saving so i guess something is going wrong in the find query.

Thanks in advance.

```
public function beforeSave() {
    if (isset($this->data['Smartphone']['model'])) {

        $brand = $this->Brand->find('first', array(
            'conditions' => array(
                'Brand.id' => $this->data['Smartphone']['brand_id']
            )
        ));

        $this->data['Smartphone']['slug'] =  $brand['slug'].'-'.Inflector::slug(strtolower($this->data['Smartphone']['model']), '-');
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: $slug = $this->Brand->field('slug', array('Brand.id' => $this->data['Smartphone']['brand_id']
)); would make it a bit cleaner even

Comment: Make sure you have latest version, i dont know if you use this in normal save() or saveAll() but in early 2.x versions saveAll and modification in callback had some issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What it looks, I think you should use `$brand['Brand']['slug']` instead of `$brand['slug']`.

You can try to print $brand array using `pr($brand);` just after the find query you have written. And provide the array index accordingly.